# Listener for enable/disable mobile data (not connected or disconnnected)

Tags: android

I test some actions (see below).

```
ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION
WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION
PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_DATA_CONNECTION_STATE (it is not actually action)
PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_DATA_CONNECTION_STATE (it is not actually action)
```

But they listen only state (connected or disconnected).

When wifi disconnected, It can listen (enable mobile data -> connnected -> broadcast - > listener)

**When wifi copnnnected, It cannot listen** (enable mobile data -> connetivity does not changed!)

I need wheather mobile data settings is enable or not

Can I listen mobile data enabled or disabled event?

Comment: **"Can I listen mobile data enabled or disabled event?"** - Why would you need to do this?

Comment: @Squonk My app need to let user know whether Mobile data is turned on or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after digging into it a bit, it doesn't seem like any broadcasts are sent out when that value is changed. Even the mobile network settings fragment in the Android Settings app doesn't listen for changes; it only checks in `onCreate()` and `onResume()`. So it seems you can't *listen* for changes, but you can get the *current* state. Unfortunately, it's a private API so you'll have to use reflection:

```
public static boolean isMobileDataEnabled(Context ctx) {
    try {
        Class<?> clazz = ConnectivityManager.class;
        Method isEnabled = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("getMobileDataEnabled", null);
        isEnabled.setAccessible(true);
        ConnectivityManager mgr = (ConnectivityManager) 
                ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        return (Boolean) isEnabled.invoke(mgr, null);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // Handle the possible case where this method could not be invoked
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I already use this code onReusme() and run timer to check state. But I need receiver.

Comment: Unfortunately, in this case it does not appear that a broadcast is triggered for this event.

Answer (score 2):

While there's no broadcast by the system for this, we can actually use a ContentObserver to get notified of when the user toggles the Mobile Data setting.

e.g:

```
ContentObserver mObserver = new ContentObserver(new Handler()) {
    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
         // Retrieve mobile data value here and perform necessary actions
    }
};

...

Uri mobileDataSettingUri = Settings.Secure.getUriFor("mobile_data");
getApplicationContext()
                .getContentResolver()
                .registerContentObserver(mobileDataSettingUri, true,
                        observer);
```

Don't forget to unregister the observer appropriately! E.g.

```
getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(mObserver);
```

Comment: i used this code worked fine in lollipop but not working in M and N.
i tried by change mobile_data to wifi_on which worked but mobile_data is not working. Can you please suggest something

Comment: Secure's mobile_data int has moved to Settings.Global since 4.2.2. you may try Uri mobileDataSettingUri = Settings.Global.getUriFor("mobile_data");